# How to change a URL query with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, twitter

i am playing around a bit with html (just using twitter for a play, not using oauth etc because i am just wanting to change a url query).

This is the current "query"

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23html5

So as you can see the query is html5

I want to in html/javascript have it so it goes like this

https://twitter.com/search?q='user entered data from a textbox'

can someone give me a bit of help with this, i know how to typically do it on a visual basic program etc but javascript/html5 got me beat even though i know its probably going to be simple

So basically the user would click an on screen button after entering text and the q would change to that.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
var search = encodeURIComponent(input.value);
url = url.replace(/?q=.*/, '?q='+ search);
```

Comment: This is my rather bad coding attempt to give you an idea of where i am at :)

Comment: <html>
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadUrl(location)
{
this.document.location.href = location;
}
</script>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="url" />
<input type=button onClick="parent.location='https://twitter.com/search?q'+url+" value='click here to visit home page'>
</body>
</html>